# Are there cases when code is compiled with Visual C++ but Visual C++ runtime is not available?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, conditional-compilation

I need to make changes to some (very) cross-platform code and add calls to [`_CrtSetDbgFlag()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function that is implemented in Visual C++ runtime. Obviously the function is only available when the code is being compiled against Visual C++ runtime headers.

I want to use `_MSC_VER` macro to conditionally include those calls.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
_CrtSetDbgFlag(value);
#endif
```

Now is there any reasonable configuration under which this wouldn't compile? Maybe I can use Visual C++ to compile code against some runtime other than Visual C++?

Is it possible that code is compiled with Visual C++ so that `_MSC_VER` is defined, but Visual C++ runtime debugging stuff is not available during compilation?

Comment: This is a non-issue.  This has nothing to do with compilation, the debugging functions are just plain functions.  It won't link.

Comment: @Hans Passant: To me it's no better - the project build is broken for someone.

Comment: Well, sure it is.  A linker error is the standard "oops, must be using the wrong library" diagnostic.  If this is at all an issue then just supply a replacement .lib with dummy functions with the same name so that it can link.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Whatever, my goal to incorporate the change in such way that all reasonable scenarios compile. Is the function call is eliminated - okay, I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes.

If the program is compiled (by MSVC) using dynamic runtime library (e.g., MSVCRTxx.DLL) AND the runtime DLL has been modified for any reason (patching, instrumentation, hook, etc), then some APIs may not work properly. The program would mostly crash. But, I don't think this is a common case.

So, if you're really concerned about this issue, you'd better compile and link this code *statically* (See [/MT compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)). This will guarantee the correct implementation of `_CrtSetDbgFlag` to be embedded in a binary.

Comment: You're theoretically right, but I don't agree with the "solution". You're basically down at the level of "if you can't trust the OS you're running on", and in that case, *anything* is suspect, and static linking won't save you *anyway*. It's simpler to just make the sane and safe assumption that if the runtime library is present, then it works as expected

Comment: The problem is not that something changes after compilation, the problem is whether there is any compilation scenario under which the above code doesn't compile.